# Exxclude ID (auto increment) from POST request in rest-layer

Tags: go

I am using https://github.com/rs/rest-layer for creating my CRUDL APIs.

In my postgres database I have a ID field (integer, auto increment).
In my schema I have ID defined like this:

```
            "id": {
                Required: false,
                ReadOnly: true,
                //OnInit: func(ctx context.Context, value interface{}) interface{} {
                // .....
                //},
                Filterable: true,
                Sortable:   true,
                Validator: &schema.Integer{
                    Boundaries: &schema.Boundaries{
                        Min: 1.0,
                        Max: math.Inf(0),
                    },
                },
            },
```

Right now I have to implement an `OnInit` function which provides a valid integer value for `ID`, otherwise the object creation fails.

Since the database generates the `id` (it is auto increment), I would like to exclude `id` field from POST requests altogether.

How can I do that? Is it even possible with this framework?

If not, then is there a way to get the new ID without actually making a call to the DB and fetch the largest ID value?

Comment: "If not, then is there a way to get the new ID without actually making a call to the DB and fetch the largest ID value?" no, and in fact calling and getting the largest ID won't work either because another request could add a record in the meantime. When using incrementing IDs, the ONLY time you can know what your new record's ID is is AFTER it is created. If you need to set IDs beforehand, you need something like UUID.

Comment: @Adrian using UUID would require changing the schema, that i don't have control over. Any other suggestion?

Comment: See my previous comment - if you need to use sequential IDs, you can only know the ID of a new record after it has been created.

Comment: @Adrian the problem that i am facing is that the framework is not allowing me to NOT send the ID in insert query during POST request. Does this mean that this framework either can't be used for my case or I have to see if i can fork the repo and add this feature.